# React TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')

Tags: reactjs, django, react-hooks, axios

I am getting this error from my frontend when i tried to register a new user, the error message from my useEffect hooks each time i click the register button

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')

Here is the code snippet

```
function Register() {
const navigate = useNavigate();

const [sendRequest, setSendRequest] = useState(false);
const [usernameValue, setUsernameValue] = useState('');
const [emailValue, setEmailValue] = useState('');
const [passwordValue, setPasswordValue] = useState('');
const [password2Value, setPassword2Value] = useState('');



function FormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The form has been submitted');
    setSendRequest(!sendRequest)
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (sendRequest) {
      const source = Axios.CancelToken.source();
      async function SignUp() {
        try {
          const response = await Axios.post(
            "http://localhost:8000/apiv1-auth-djoser/users/",
            {
              username: usernameValue,
              email: emailValue,
              password: passwordValue,
              re_password: password2Value,
            },
            { cancelToken: source.token }
          );
          console.log(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response)
        }
      }
      SignUp();
      return () => {
        source.cancel();
      };
    }
}, [sendRequest]);
```

return (
<div
style={{
width: "50%",
marginLeft: "auto",
marginRight: "auto",
marginTop: "3rem",
border: "5px solid black",
padding: "3rem",
}}
>


CREATE AN ACCOUNT

```
    <Grid item container style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
      <TextField
        id="username"
        label="Username"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
        value={usernameValue}
        onChange={(e) => setUsernameValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Grid>

    <Grid item container style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
      <TextField
        id="email"
        label="Email"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
        value={emailValue}
        onChange={(e) => setEmailValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Grid>

    <Grid item container style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
      <TextField
        id="password"
        label="Password"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
        value={passwordValue}
        onChange={(e) => setPasswordValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Grid>

    <Grid item container style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
      <TextField
        id="password2"
        label="Confirm Password"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
        value={password2Value}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword2Value(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Grid>

    <Grid
      item
      container
      xs={8}
      style={{ marginTop: "1rem", marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: "auto" }}
    >
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        fullWidth
        type="submit"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#ff6c38",
          color: "white",
          fontSize: "1.1rem",
          marginLeft: "1rem",
          // "&:hover": {
          //    backgroundColor: "blue",
          // },
        }}
      >
        SIGN UP
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  </form>

  <Grid
    item
    container
    justifyContent="center"
    style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}
  >
    <Typography variant="small">
      Already have an account?{" "}
      <span
        onClick={() => navigate("/login")}
        style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "#ff6c38" }}
      >
        SIGN IN
      </span>
    </Typography>
  </Grid>
</div>
```

);
}

Comment: Where does the `Axios` come from and what's the version of `axios`?